# In Excel or Power BI, how can I assign 'ongoing project' to each date in a year, when I only have the start and end date of each project?

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have two tables (see attached workbook).

One with the names of all projects in first column, the start date of the project in that row in the second column and the end date of that project in the third column.

The other table has a column with all the dates in a year. I want to add several columns to it. My question is how to get the one that I coloured yellow in the workbook. That column should contain the project that will be/was in process for each day of the year.

I hope the workbook will illustrate my problem.

Sneak peak:

Table one

| Project ID | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2/1/2020 | 3/1/2020 |
| B | 5/1/2020 | 10/1/2020 |
| Etc. | Etc. | Etc. |

Table two

| Each Date in a year | Ongoing project |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 |  |
| 2/1/2020 | A |
| 3/1/2020 | A |
| 4/1/2020 |  |
| 5/1/2020 | B |
| Etc. | Etc. |

[image: Image of workbook]

So far I have tried several approaches: Index/match, xlookup, dynamic arrays.

Edit:

Excel Wizard (YouTube) provided a solution that helped me out.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(TableOne[Project ID],([@Each Date in a year]>=TableOne[Start Date])*(@Each Date in a year]<=TableOne[End Date])))
```

Comment: In Power Query you could create a column with all the dates of the year, then merge your data table. You can probably do something similar in Power BI

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't figure out how to link the columns in Power Query to get the right merge. Excel Wizard (YouTube) shared an Excel formula that does the trick. I will add it to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query you could:

- Transform your table 1 into a table where each ProjectID/Date has a single row
- Create a second table consisting of all the dates in the time period
- Join the two tables with a `JoinKind.FullOuter`

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Project ID", type text}, {"Start Date", type date}, {"End Date", type date}}),
    
    //show one row for each projectID/Date
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "dtRange", each 
            List.Dates([Start Date], Duration.TotalDays([End Date] - [Start Date]) + 1,#duration(1,0,0,0))),
    #"Expanded dtRange" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "dtRange"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded dtRange",{{"dtRange", type date}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Start Date", "End Date"}),

//not sure what you want for the calendar range
//but you can set it in the next two steps
dtStart = #date(2021,12,3),
calDays = 365,
dtTbl = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
            Table.FromList(
                List.Dates(dtStart,calDays,#duration(1,0,0,0)),
                Splitter.SplitByNothing(),{"Dates"},null,ExtraValues.Error),
            {{"Dates", type date}}),

//combine the two tables
joinTbl = Table.Join(dtTbl,"Dates",#"Removed Columns","dtRange",JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(joinTbl,{"dtRange"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Dates", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{{"Project ID", "Ongoing Project"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

**Sample Data**

[image]

**Results**  *note that multiple non-project date rows are hidden*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your additional reply. I am going to take a look at this method also.

Comment: @Coen if you need help with the other "results" columns, let me know.